# How to find corner points of a polygon composed of squares?

Tags: algorithm, graph, path, vertex

A group of adjacent squares compose a polygon, all coordinates of 4 vertexes of the squares are known, but order of squares is unknown.

In the example image, I highlight all corner points by red dots. If connect them in correct order, a full shape can be restored like place squares at correct positions.

[image: Example]

So the question is, how to find the red dots, and their order?

And maybe a further question is what if the shape has some holes?

Comment: Do you only have the coordinates of every square, with no particular order ?

Comment: Yes, only coordinates of squares, no order known.

Comment: You can create an image where you draw the squares (2x2), then use a contouring function and analyze it to extract the turning points.

Comment: Alternatively, you can output all edges of all squares, and discard all duplicate pairs. Then form one or more loops by matching the common endpoints. Two aligned edges can be merged into one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Count how many times each vertex occurs in your input.  The ones that occur an odd number of times are your "corners".  Mark these vertices as "corners".
2. Count how many times each edge occurs in your input.  Edges that occur only once are your "outer-edges", mark these as outer (the edges that occur twice are inner-edges, we don't care about them).
3. Pick a "corner" with one or more unused outer-edges at random, follow one of it's outer-edges in a straight line (i.e., keeping the same direction) through the "even" vertices until you reach another corner (odd vertex).
4. Continue out from the new corner, using only previously unused straight-edges.  When you return to your starting corner, you have completed a list of corners in-order for that (semi?-)connected shape.
5. If there are still corners with unused outer-edges then pick one of them at random and go to step #3.  Repeat this step until all corners' outer-edges are accounted for.

Comment: (Note: revised)

Comment: The "odd-even" rule is neat and helps a lot.

I find a case if two squares are sharing only one common vertex but not an edge, this rule may not work. In other words, two squares like this should not be seen as connected. So the "odd-even" rule is necessary but no sufficient condition in logical terms.

Another thing I do not understand is step 2, "if you come to the end of a straight line of edges, but it is not a corner". Clearly, it's a deep-first search algorithm, but I can't depict this case in my mind, could you give me an example? 

Thank you very much.

Comment: I did consider the case of diagonal squares, in which case it would not count as a corner, but the algorithm still works by passing straight through the intersection. it should come back around later and pass through the remaining edges straight, ultimately still closing the loop and counting the two shapes as one (which is OK, we aren't counting shapes anyway).  I have assumed that by "corners in-order" you meant "drawing order", which this would fulfill.  Let me know if you meant something else.

Comment: As for rule 2, yeah it doesn't seem quite right, let me think about it ... OK, I think I can fix it ...  OK, I think that I have fixed the algorithm by adding the concept of "outer" edges.  See above.